# expected unqualified-id before numeric constant in STK code

Tags: c++, iphone, sound-synthesis

I included the The Synthesis ToolKit in C++ (STK) from stanford into my project and when I try to build I get the following error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

in the second line written here, from the STK.h: (in the part where they declare their namespace)

```
const StkFloat PI = 3.14159265358979;
const StkFloat TWO_PI   = 2 * PI;
```

My code was compiling before I added this, and surely there wouldn't be such a simple error in the STK code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you missing the namespace for the type `StkFloat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that some evil header defines `PI` as a macro.

Either find and destroy that header, or put `#undef PI` before including the toolkit header.